# I got an error in installing 64 bit xampp in my 32 bit os?

Tags: xampp, cpu-architecture

Im trying to install xampp in ubuntu 16.04 32 bit 
how can I solve this error

```
/Downloads$ chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-5.6.28-0-installer.run
/Downloads$ ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.28-0-installer.run
bash: ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.28-0-installer.run: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

I also tried this code but it don't work

```
/Downloads$ chmod 7777 xampp-linux-x64-5.6.28-0-installer.run
/Downloads$ ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.28-0-installer.run
bash: ./xampp-linux-x64-5.6.28-0-installer.run: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error
```

what I do?

Comment: And just for reference, if you have an Intel Core-i CPU, Pentium, Celeron, etc., or an AMD A-Series APU or FX-series APU, you should be using `Ubuntu 64-bit`. ***64-bit CPUs are compatible with 32-bit applications***, but ***not vice-versa***.

Answer (score 3):

You can not install 64 bit applications on a 32 bit OS.
You need to find 32 bits versions to install .. if they exists.